# Handling 422 errors when logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, http-status-code-422

I'm currently handling 422 errors(an invalid auth token was passed to rails) and I currently redirect the user to a separate page. This works well but what I've discovered is that if a user logs in and hits a 422 error during that log in request, the user goes to the separate page AND is now logged in. Ideally I want the user to not be logged in.

I currently user Devise(3.4.1) for authentication. No custom code has been written outside of the code written below.

How do I prevent the user from logging in when they hit a 422 error and not be logged in?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # This method is called whenever a CSRF token is invalid.
  def handle_unverified_request
    # By default this method raises ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
    redirect_to '/422'
  end
end
```

Comment: Rails does not have built-in functionality for authentication. Please provide more information on how you're handling this, whether it's a gem or custom implementation.

Comment: Updated my answer. Btw I use Devise for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def handle_unverified_request
  super # call the default behaviour, including Devise override
  authenticate_user!
end
```

Comment: I played around with that when I realized Devise overrides the method. The problem is that I receive the following error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` which occurs from calling `super`.